# Call Javascript function onchange of f:selectitems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am new to jquery. My project invovles primefaces 4.0, jsf 2.1 (xhtml).

I have a select all boolean checkbox, and a selectmanycheckbox which is filled using a list retreived from the server side.

```
<p:tab title="Service Status" >
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="Select All"
        value="#{myBean.selectAllStatus}"
        id="selectAllStatus" style="margin-left:4px;" onchange="selectAllStatus(this);" >
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox
        value="#{myBean.serviceStatusFilterList}"
        layout="pageDirection" id="empListSub">

        <f:param name="tabValue" value="1" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{serviceCalendarViewBean.serviceStatusList}" var="status"
            itemLabel="#{status.title}" itemValue="#{status.id}"/>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:tab>
</p:accordion>
```

The Javascript called when the 'select all' checkbox is clicked is

```
function selectAllStatus(element)
{
   var selectAll = element.checked;
   $( 'input[id^="'accord:empListSub'"]' ).each(function(){
        this.checked=selectAll;
   });
}
```

When i uncheck the 'select all' checkbox, i need the all checkboxs generated by f:selectitems to be unchecked and vice versa.

The below code in the change event's javascript gave me an error in the console.
Error is "unexpected syntax error ; "

```
$( 'input[id^="'accord:empListSub'"]' ).each(function(){
    this.checked=selectAll;
});
```

In the network the javascript code appears as

```
$( 'input[id^=&quot;'accord:empListSub'&quot;]' ).each(function(){
     this.checked=selectAll;
});
```

I tried removing the double quote which was of no use.

So could anybody help me out here.

In jquery, When i uncheck the 'select all' checkbox, i need the all checkboxs generated by f:selectitems to be unchecked and vice versa.

And also when i check or uncheck any of the f:selectItems it also has to call another javascript function.

How do i do that?

Comment: I *think* the problem is that Primefaces uses theming for checkboxes so you can't just do it the normal jquery way. You have to fiddle with showing/hiding the check-image on the container. I tried it but failed, but I think its possible

Comment: You forgot to tell the PrimeFaces version.

Comment: PrimeFaces 4.1 doesn't exist. At least, not as final/official release.

Comment: sorry :)..my mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the component referencing

```
$( 'input[name^=accord\\:empListSub]' ).each(function(i,obj){
    $('div .ui-chkbox-box').addClass('ui-state-active');
    $('span .ui-chkbox-icon').addClass('ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c');
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** in jQuery to set the checked property

```
 $( 'input[id^='+accord:empListSub+']' ).prop("checked",selectAll);
```